# SQL Server 2008R2 - Stored Procedure with 2 updates causing deadlocks

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, deadlock

I have a web api web service that calls an authentication stored procedure.
This stored procedure calls a different stored procedure that does 1 update:

```
UPDATE  AccountLicensingDeviceConnectionsPerPeriod 
SET     DateLastConnected = GETDATE(),
        ConnectionPermitted = @IsValid
WHERE   AccountId = @AccountId
        AND UserId = @UserId
        AND Device = @Device
```

And then does a different update:

```
UPDATE  Users 
SET     DateLastLoggedIn = GETDATE(),
        LastLoggedInDevice = @Device,
        InvalidLoginCount = 0
WHERE   Id = @UserId
```

These updates are always in the same order or at least they should be, is there any way to avoid 2 concurrent processes to deadlock?

The deadlock graph:
[image: deadlock graph]
[Deadlock graph data extracted](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/204180/deadlock_DEV6_3.xdl)

[GetIsAccountLicenseConnectionValid SP](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/204180/GetIsAccountLicenseConnectionValid.sql)

AuthenticateUser SP - h**ps://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/204180/AuthenticateUser.sql

Comment: The "*Deadlock graph data extracted*" appears to have little or no relationship to the "*deadlock graph*" you posted?

Comment: What does `GetIsAccountLicenseConnectionValid` do? Can you post that definition? It would also be useful to see the whole code block, to give information about sequencing as well as transactions and isolation semantics.

Comment: Had posted wrong image, it wasn't related with the extracted graph data.

Comment: And can you show the stored procedure that calls this other stored procedure?

Answer (score 2):

Using [SentryOne Plan Explorer](https://sentryone.com/plan-explorer) I was able to make a little more sense of the deadlock graph ([click to embiggen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIuzR.png)):

> [image]

The victim also called the stored procedure `GetIsAccountLicenseConnectionValid`, and I suspect this procedure has some touch against one or both tables affected by the updates in the question. It is certainly feasible that locks taken by that stored procedure could interfere with locks affecting another transaction that hasn't called that stored procedure yet.